# my Database is not showing on admin panel

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

## models.py

from django.db import models

class complain(models.Model):

```
name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=120)
Email = models.CharField(max_length=120)
message = models.CharField(max_length = 600)


def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

## views.py

```
def contact(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    form = ComplainForm()
else:
    form = ComplainForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        email = form.cleaned_data['Email']
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']
        try:
            send_mail(name, message, email, ['ankushbanik123@gmail.com']) # change this to your email
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        return redirect('/success')
return render(request, "tem/home.html", {'form': form})
```

"""You need a success view for when the form has been submitted. This will render the thank you message once the user has submitted the form. Then on the urls.py, import successView then add path('success', successView, name='success'),"""
def successView(request):
    return render(request, "tem/success.html")

## form.py

```
class ComplainForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = complain
    fields = ['name', 'Email', 'message',]

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

        return email
```

## admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
```

## Register your models here.

```
from .models import complain
```

## admin.site.register(complain)

```
class complainAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'Email', 'message')

admin.site.register(complain, complainAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct in `admin.py`. Have you reloading your server to refresh your Python code? I personally bound an alias to the command to do that.

```sh
alias refresh='sudo systemctl restart gunicorn;sudo systemctl reload nginx'
```

This would look different for you if you're using different programs than me.

P.S. `forms.py` and `views.py` are not relevant since your not importing them.

Comment: i am ususing windows... i can not use sudo... now tell me what i can do??

Comment: Ouch. I'm sorry, but I'm not going to be much help in that case. I run Windows on my local machine, but I use remote access into a Ubuntu server for development. While Python does treat Windows as a first class citizen (I think - can't find a reference ATM), the same can't be said for a lot of the other programs.